# Flex and Bison Calculator

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to implement a calculator for nor expressions, such as `true nor true nor (false nor false)` using Flex and Bison, but I keep getting my error message back. Here is my .l file:

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%% 
("true"|"false")    {return BOOLEAN;}

.|\n    {yyerror();}

%%

int main(void)
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
     return 0;
}
int yyerror(void)
{
     printf("Error\n");
}
```

Here is my .y file:

```
/* Bison declarations.  */
 %token BOOLEAN
 %left 'nor'

 %% /* The grammar follows.  */
 input:
   /* empty */
 | input line
 ;

 line:
   '\n'
 | exp '\n'  { printf ("%s",$1); }
 ;

 exp:
   BOOLEAN            { $$ = $1;           }
 | exp 'nor' exp      { $$ = !($1 || $3);  }
 | '(' exp ')'        { $$ = $2;           }
 ;
 %%
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to handle all the single-character tokens, which as @vitaut correctly says you aren't handling at all yet, is to return `yytext[0]` for the dot rule, and let the parser sort out which ones are legal.

You have also lost the values of the BOOLEANs 'true' and 'false', which should be stored into yylval as 1 and 0 respectively, which will then turn up in `$1,` `$3` etc. If you're going to have more datatypes in the longer term, you need to look into the `%union` directive.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get errors is that your lexer only recognizes one type of token, namely `BOOLEAN`, but not the newline, parentheses or `nor` (and you produce an error for everything else). For single letter tokens like parentheses and the newline you can return the character itself as a token type:

```
\n { return '\n'; }
```

For `nor` thought you should introduce a token type like you did for `BOOLEAN` and add an appropriate rule to the lexer.